# Recursively find a node and recursively change it's access

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree, treeview

I have this tree data:

```
type DataType = {
  id: string;
  access: 'view' | 'none';
  isDisabled: boolean;
  children: DataType[];
};

export const Data: DataType = {
  id: '1',
  access: 'view',
  isDisabled: false,
  children: [
    {
      id: '2',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '3',
          access: 'view',
          isDisabled: false,
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [],
    },
  ],
};
```

What I want to do is when a node's access changes, the isDisabled boolean will change based on the following rules:

If access is 'view', the isDisabled will remain false if access is 'none', the isDisabled in the current node will be false, but it's children's isDisabled will be true.

I have these functions: (not working as I hoped)

```
// this will find the node
const find = (
  data: DataType,
  selectedId: string,
  selectedAccess: 'view' | 'none'
) => {
  if (selectedId && selectedAccess) {
    if (data.id === selectedId) {
      data = changeAccess(data, selectedId, selectedAccess);
    } else {
      data.children.forEach((child) => find(child, selectedId, selectedAccess));
    }
  }
};

// this will change the access and isDisabled
const changeAccess = (
  data: DataType,
  selectedId: string,
  selectedAccess: 'view' | 'none'
): DataType => ({
  id: data.id,
  access: selectedAccess,
  isDisabled:
    data.id !== selectedId && selectedAccess !== 'view' ? true : false, // condition to toggle the isDisabled
  children: data.children?.map((child) =>
    changeAccess(child, selectedId, selectedAccess)
  ),
});
```

So if I call the find function with:

```
find(Data, '2', 'none');
```

The result will be:

```
const DataAfter: DataType = {
  id: '1',
  access: 'view',
  isDisabled: false,
  children: [
    {
      id: '2',
      access: 'none', // changed from 'view' to 'none'
      isDisabled: false, // remain false
      children: [
        {
          id: '3',
          access: 'none', // changed from 'view' to 'none'
          isDisabled: true, // changed from false to true
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      access: 'view',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '5',
          access: 'view',
          isDisabled: false,
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

And if I call find again with:

```
find(Data, '4', 'none');
```

The result will be: (notice the pervious call mutated the array and is reflected here as well for id 2 & 3)

```
const DataAfter2: DataType = {
  id: '1',
  access: 'view',
  isDisabled: false,
  children: [
    { // id 2 & 3 remains changed from the pervious call.
      id: '2',
      access: 'none',
      isDisabled: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: '3',
          access: 'none',
          isDisabled: true,
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      access: 'none', // changed from 'view' to 'none'
      isDisabled: false, // remain false
      children: [
        {
          id: '5',
          access: 'none', // changed from 'view' to 'none'
          isDisabled: true, // changed from false to true
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

And if I call find with:

```
find(Data, '1', 'none');
```

All access will be 'none' and only id:1 will have it's isDisabled boolean equal false.

And finally, if I call find with:

```
find(Data, '1', 'view');
```

All access will change to 'view' and all isDisabled with be false.

My functions isn't working as I hoped. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Apologies if you have seen a similar question, I'm fairly new to recursion and tree data and want to practice using it in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
data = changeAccess(data, selectedId, selectedAccess)
```

will get a new object into the `data` variable, but that is not mutating the original `data`... it is a reassignment, throwing away the previous reference that `data` had, and (since JavaScript does not have call-by-reference) the caller will not see the new object.

As you want to mutate the given data structure, you should not have `changeAccess` return a new object. It should mutate it:

```
const find = (
  data: DataType,
  selectedId: string,
  selectedAccess: 'view' | 'none'
) => {
  if (selectedId && selectedAccess) {
    if (data.id === selectedId) {
      changeAccess(data, selectedId, selectedAccess); // No return value
    } else {
      data.children.forEach((child) => find(child, selectedId, selectedAccess));
    }
  }
};

const changeAccess = (
  data: DataType,
  selectedId: string,
  selectedAccess: 'view' | 'none'
) => Object.assign(data, { // Mutate `data`
  access: selectedAccess,
  isDisabled:
    data.id !== selectedId && selectedAccess !== 'view', // already boolean
  children: data.children?.map((child) =>
    changeAccess(child, selectedId, selectedAccess)
  ),
});
```

Comment: Thank you trinoct for answering this question as well :)

Comment: You were right regarding the Object.assign, I used it here instead Object.assign(data, changeAccess(data, selectedId, selectedAccess))